# how to change the background of hub title with random colors and change image pixel of hubtile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have prepared a custom hubtile which has a image and textbloxk for displaying the image and text needed.I have hardcoded the background color of tiles as white,Now can anyone suggest how to change the background of tiles with multiple colors and also can any one suggest to change the color of image(i.e change pixel of image coming from server which is used as HubTile source). I have been using below code

**xaml file code**

```
<Style x:Key="HomePageTabStyle"
       TargetType="toolkit:HubTile">
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="173" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="173" />
   <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="White" />
    <!--<Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />-->
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:HubTile">
                <Border x:Name="Container">
                    <Border.Resources>
                        <CubicEase x:Key="HubTileEaseOut"
                                   EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                    </Border.Resources>
                    <Border.Height>
                        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource HeightConverter}"
                                 Path="Size"
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                    </Border.Height>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ImageStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="ExpandedToSemiexpanded"
                                                  From="Expanded"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85"
                                                  To="Semiexpanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                  Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.85"
                                                                  Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-0.4566, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                  Value="0.0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="SemiexpandedToExpanded"
                                                  From="Semiexpanded"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85"
                                                  To="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                  Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-0.4566, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.85"
                                                                  Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="SemiexpandedToCollapsed"
                                                  From="Semiexpanded"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85"
                                                  To="Collapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                  Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-0.4566, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.85"
                                                                  Value="0.0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="CollapsedToExpanded"
                                                  From="Collapsed"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85"
                                                  To="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                  Value="0.0" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.85"
                                                                  Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="ExpandedToFlipped"
                                                  From="Expanded"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85"
                                                  To="Flipped">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                  Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185"
                                                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="BackPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185"
                                                                    Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                  Value="0.0" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.85"
                                                                  Value="180.0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="FlippedToExpanded"
                                                  From="Flipped"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85"
                                                  To="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                  Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185"
                                                                    Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="BackPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185"
                                                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                  Value="180.0" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.85"
                                                                  Value="360.0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="0.0"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                                Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Semiexpanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-0.4566, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Flipped">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="180.0"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                                Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="BackPanel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                                Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border.Width>
                        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource WidthConverter}"
                                 Path="Size"
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                    </Border.Width>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="Viewport"
                                Height="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                Width="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <StackPanel.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection x:Name="ViewportProjection"
                                             CenterOfRotationY="0.25" />
                        </StackPanel.Projection>
                        <Grid x:Name="TitlePanel"
                              Height="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=2, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                              Width="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform />
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <Grid x:Name="BackPanel"
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                  Height="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  Width="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <Grid.Projection>
                                    <PlaneProjection CenterOfRotationY="0.5"
                                                     RotationX="180" />
                                </Grid.Projection>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <!--Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"-->
                                <!--<TextBlock x:Name="NotificationBlock"
                                           Foreground="Gray"
                                           FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                                           LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                                           LineHeight="32"
                                           Margin="8,8,0,6"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Notification}" />-->
                                <!--Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"-->
                                <!--<TextBlock x:Name="MessageBlock"
                                           Foreground="{StaticResource AppFontColor}"
                                           FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                                           LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                                           LineHeight="23.333"
                                           Margin="10,10,10,6"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Message}" />-->
                                <!--Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"-->
                                <!--<TextBlock x:Name="BackTitleBlock"
                                           Foreground="Gray"
                                           FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
                                           Margin="10,0,0,6"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />-->
                            </Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="Image"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Grid.Row="1">
                                <Image Height="80"
                                       Width="90"
                                       Margin="0,0,0,35"
                                       Source="{TemplateBinding Source}"
                                       Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                <!--<Image Height="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                       Source="{TemplateBinding Source}"
                                       Stretch="Uniform"
                                       Width="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />-->
                            </Border>
                            <!--Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"-->
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black"
                                       Grid.Row="2"
                                       FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                                       LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                                       LineHeight="27"
                                       MaxHeight="54"
                                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                                       Margin="10,0,0,6"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And **C# file** for it is

```
tile = new HubTile()
                {
                    Name = currentTab.TAB_ID,
                    Title = currentTab.TAB_NAME,
                    Message = currentTab.TAB_NAME,
                    Notification = currentTab.DESCRIPTION,
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(currentTab.ICON_URL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
                    IsFrozen = true,
                    //Foreground = tabForegroundBrush,
                    //Background = tabBackgroungBrush,
                    DataContext = currentTab,
                    Margin = new Thickness(4),
                    Style = App.Current.Resources["HomePageTabStyle"] as Style,
                    Size = TileSize.Medium
                };
```

Here **currentTab** is object of class.

Please any one do suggest a working solution for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Array of Colors**,I achieved point one.

```
Color[] colors=new Color{Colors.Red,Colors.Blue,Colors.White}
```

and in hubtile code added below line

```
Background=new SolidColorBrush(index % colors.Length),
```

Thanks.

Hope it helps someone.